# Form with attachments upload and email sending

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to make **form with a textarea and an image upload field**. When somebody submit it I want it to **send email** (with text from textarea) **with attachements** (from input file upload field) **to me**.

My simple form looks like that:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>        
            @Html.TextArea("Question");      
            <input type="file"/> 
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />

    </fieldset>

}
```

I found PHP scripts that are doing something like that, but how could I do it in ASP.NET MVC (could be with JavaScript)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's an example using gmail's SMTP but if you have your own SMTP server you could easily adapt the code.

As always I would start with a view model:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Question { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new QuestionViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(QuestionViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
        {
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someaccount@gmail.com", "secret");
            var mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("fromaddress@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("toaddress@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "Test mail";
            mail.Body = model.Question;
            if (model.Attachment != null && model.Attachment.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var attachment = new Attachment(model.Attachment.InputStream, model.Attachment.FileName);
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        return Content("email sent", "text/plain");
    }
}
```

and finally a view:

```
@model QuestionViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>        
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Question)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Question)
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="attachment">Attachment</label>
            <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment"/> 
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

A further improvement to this code would be to externalize the actual sending of the mail into a repository implementing some interface and using DI in order to weaken the coupling between the controller logic and the mail sending logic.

Note that you can also configure your SMTP settings in web.config:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="fromaddress@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network 
          enableSsl="true" 
          host="smtp.gmail.com" 
          port="587" 
          userName="someaccount@gmail.com" 
          password="secret" 
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

and then simply:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add("toaddress@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Test mail";
    mail.Body = model.Question;
    if (model.Attachment != null && model.Attachment.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var attachment = new Attachment(model.Attachment.InputStream, model.Attachment.FileName);
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    }
    client.Send(mail);
}
```

Comment: toaddress? I didn't know toads wore dresses!

Comment: What if you tried to use a $.ajax to pass your `HttpPostedFileBase` file? I'm trying to do it throught a simple $.ajax call, but i got a null file on my controller. Is it the content type i'm missing?

Comment: @AdrianoRR, it is very difficult to upload files using AJAX. There are some components out there that do it like http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ In order to upload a file you need to use `multipart/form-data` enctype.

Comment: Well i didn't know about this difficulty. And yes, i'm already using `multipart/form-data` which is fine if i use a normal submit action, but not if i handle the .submit event with jquery. I'll check this component you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Oh i forgot! If i use `Ajax.BeginForm()` - the bad MS ajax script - i can get a `HttpPostedFileBase` file on my controller. Don't know how it recognizes it, but it does.

Comment: @AdrianoRR, are you sure that you are performing a real AJAX request? Maybe you forgot to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page in which case the Ajax.BeginForm helper behaves as a normal form?

Comment: Oh i see! Yes, i've removed `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`. That explains why it worked back then. Well, i still have to do this through an ajax call, since my upload occurs in a `jquery.dialog()`. Thanks for your help Darin!

Comment: Cool sample Darin. Helped me forward a LOT!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i have been trying to do this all afternoon, this worked first try!

Answer (score 3):

MailMessage class in .NET should be able to handle that for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx

Or are you looking for something more specific to your actual code? (e.g. how to read the file and add it to the attachment)?

Comment: Yes I am looking for something more specific - how to read file from form and add it as attachment to email and then send this email.

Comment: Sorry, too slow, but glad someone got you the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (model.Attachment != null && model.Attachment.ContentLength > 0)
    {
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase item in fileUploader)
      {

        var attachment = new Attachment(model.Attachment.InputStream,   model.Attachment.FileName);
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Daren's answer, you don't have to hardcode the input and label for your file upload in your view. Just slap this in there :)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Attachment, new { type = "file" })
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attachment)
```