# Can ASP.MVC 3 partial view Attach one file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, email-attachments

I have one partial view in my solution that I want to use to send an email.
Using this post : [Form with attachments upload and email sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282049/form-with-attachments-upload-and-email-sending)

I found a good way to send emails with attachment, but It doesn't work when I use partialView.
My Object at my post gets null at Attachment attribute, but it works right when I use View.
I also used Ajax.BeginForm and it works right in View, but like Html.BeginForm it doesn't work in PartialView.
So, my question is: How can I get one attachment when I use partialView??

Comment: Whoever voted to close, please comment before voting to close.  This obviously is a real question.  It addresses a practical situation that the user is actually experiencing.  Everything about it is **real**.  If you think it is vague then it would better to first ask for clarifications before voting to close.

Comment: Have you specified the `enctype` attribute to `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: You will have to show your code if you expect some help.

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug to view the actual posted values( Net->HTML->Post->Post tab ).  Sometimes posted values are posted as "ModelInstance.PropertyName" rather than just "PropertyName".  In which case the only way I've found to retrieve the value is using Request.Form["ModelInstance.PropertyName"]

The source of the post should look something like this.  The value of the name="attachment" will give you a clue into a binding problem.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------132452512814062 
Content-Length: 694 -----------------------------132452512814062 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment"; filename="new 2.txt" 
Content-Type: text/plain

blah blah blh blah
asdlkjdslakjsd
```

Comment: I found nothing about attachment on firebug and Request.Form["ModelInstance.PropertyName"], just the question and X-Requested-With.
I don't know why it appears no Attachment.
Is it a problem with MVC partialView?

Comment: @Fernando Please edit your original post to include the source of the Post:  In your form, select a file and hit the Send button to post the form.  Then copy and paste the source from the Post tab in firebug.  Make sure you are under the Post tab and not the Headers tab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your rendered html, view source, and look at the id's and names and make sure whatever code you're using is using the same id's and names.

Comment: I copied and pasted all the source on a new project and it works fine.
But it really don't work when I use partialView, I don't know why.

Comment: @Fernando Juarez - Partial views are just placeholders.  They stick whatever code is in them in the output.  If the code is identical, it will work, because partial views don't do anything to the HTML.  The browser sees the same code.  Obviously, something must be different between the rendered html in your two situations.  So look at the actual HTML output and see what's wrong.